# How to continuing playing music when user move through the app. [Not in background mode]

Tags: swift, singleton, avaudioplayer, swift5

I'm making a musicPlayer app in Swift, which is based on Tab Bar Controller and now is creating the NowPlayingViewController which present the playing scene as below screenshot showed. This NowPlayingViewController will be opened when I click the table row from another tableViewController, and the song was played.

My question is that when I dismiss this View Controller to go back the previous view or move to other view of Tab Bar Controller, the music playing is stoped. After some googles, someone suggests to use **singleton** to make a shared session for music playing.

[image]

/// here is my project's storyboard
[image]

/// I change my code to add one **Audio Manager.swift** as the singleton class. However I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing, need help. Also don't find method about getting playingSong variable from NowPlayingVewController...

```
import AVKit

class AudioManager {
    // use Singleton pattern keep the music continuing when user move through the App.
    static let sharedInstance = AudioManager()

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var playingSong: SongData?

    private init() {
        // config for audio background playing
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func startMusic() {
        do {
            // how to retrieve the playingSong variable from NowPlayingViewController?
            // playingSong =
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: playingSong!.url)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch {
            print("could not load file")
        }
    }

    func pauseMusic() {
       audioPlayer.pause()
    }
}
```

/// **NowPlayViewController.swift**, in case it is not fully aligned with above picture because it is just an example image to show the playing scene.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class NowPlayingViewController: UIViewController {

    var playingSong: SongData?
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var isPlaying = true
    var timer:Timer!

    @IBOutlet weak var songTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var songAlbum: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var songArtwork: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playOrPauseButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        songTitle.text = playingSong?.songName
        songAlbum.text = playingSong?.albumName
        songArtwork.image = playingSong?.albumArtwork

        // start play music in AudioManager sharedInstance
        AudioManager.sharedInstance.startMusic()
    }

    @IBAction func NaviBack(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("press button")
        // not sure about this, use present modally of segue,
        // so need to use dismiss to return to the previous scene/view.
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func PlayOrPauseMusic(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if isPlaying {
            print("isPlaying")
            AudioManager.sharedInstance.pauseMusic()
            isPlaying = false
            playOrPauseButton.setTitle("Pause", for: .normal)
        } else {
            print("isPaused")
            AudioManager.sharedInstance.startMusic()
            isPlaying = true
            playOrPauseButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

/// Sending data to NowPlayingViewController from tableViewController using Segue present modally.

```
// define segue to the transition to NowPlaying View
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "playingSong" {
             if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let controller = segue.destination as! NowPlayingViewController
                if resultSearchController.isActive {
                    controller.playingSong = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
                } else {
                    controller.playingSong = tableData[indexPath.row]
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The guys at talk.objc.io did a couple of episodes on this a while back. The first is freely viewable and may be all you need : https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E86-sharing-state-between-view-controllers-in-mvc-part-1

Comment: @Chris, thanks for the reference. It could be what I want as that two guys design a like Apple music mini playing scene, which one need to show on top of each scene. And they are using MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I found my AudioManger is actually worked by getting the playingSong: SongData from tableViewController when user click the cell row in this view. I declare this playingSong as static var in order to access/use it from AudioManager.

Now music is playing when user navigation through the Tab Bar Controller, update my code as below. Next step could be add a button on the left/right top of navi view to re-present the playing scene:)

Err, I found that it still has issue, the play and resume for the current song is working, but if I select another song in the tableViewController, then it still plays the previous song in NowPlayingView. The reason could be the init() only once, so I need to find a way to re-assign value to sharedInstance when select another cell row.

```
import AVKit

class AudioManager {
    // use Singleton pattern keep the music continuing when user move through the App.
    static let sharedInstance = AudioManager()

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    var playingSong: SongData?

    private init() {
        // config for audio background playing
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        do {
            playingSong = SongsTableViewController.playingSong
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: playingSong!.url)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch {
            print("could not load file")
        }
    }

    func playMusic() {
       audioPlayer.play()
    }

    func pauseMusic() {
       audioPlayer.pause()
    }

}
```